# Django Pagination on a Changing Queryset

Tags: python, django, pagination

On one of my pages I would like to display a subset of a sorted list of objects. The entire list of relevant objects is extremely long and has a good chance of changing while the user is viewing the page. I don't mind that the page is not up to date, but I do need to ensure that when the user goes to the next page, the user will see the next n objects from the original sorted list. Thus, due to potentially changed data, using django's built in pagination or a really nice library like [Django-endless-pagination](http://code.google.com/p/django-endless-pagination/) will not return the correct results when going to the "next page".

To give an example of what I mean, say we have objects [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12] and want to display 5 per page, sorted from small to big. The first page would look like:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

But while viewing this page, 3 and 4 were deleted. If we go to the "next" page, pagination will re-query the set and return:

8, 9, 10, 11, 12

I realize this is pagination's expected behavior, but I would like an easy way to make the next page display:

6, 7, 8, 9, 10

The most obvious solution is to do some client side pagination, and I realize there is a [nice jquery library](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination) for this, but the number of objects can be potentially way too big for this solution to be realistic.

Is there a simple approach to paginate on a queryset and continue to use the results returned from that original queryset instead of re-fetching the queryset that may have changed?

Thanks for any insight you can give me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What might be a possibly solution is if you create your own pagination function that instead of the next link referring to a certain page it could pass a record that is the top record on the next page

The problem is that this would only work if the items being added/changed are only the first items in a list

Comment: +1 for a nice suggestion and pointing out its pitfall. Similarly, I could possibly store the value of the top record on the next page and grab all the results that come after that.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as accepted because you're the only one to help me out on this and your suggestion is pretty good. So, thanks!

Comment: Yea thats more or less what i meant glad to help, and thanks for the vote (means i can actually comment and vote now :) )